# Sequelize config.json / config.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I use express and sequelize for the creation of a web server. I use the CLI of sequelize for the creation of models and migrations.

I would like to change the `config.json` to `config.js` in order to be able to use environment variables.

I followed the documentation and created the `.sequelizerc' file as follows =>

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('migrations')
}
```

This works as it should for the CLI sequelize, I can create models or start migrations but I can't start the server because it looks for the file `config.json`.

So my question is how to make sure that when the server starts, it is able to read `config.js`.

When i run `node bin/www` i receive

```
Error: Cannot find module '/nodeTest/nodejs-relationships/models/../config/config.json'
```

Comment: How are you call config in your server app?

Comment: No, since everything is preconfigured with sequelize, I have no idea how to proceed

Answer (score 4):

The problem was actually my `index.js` file located in the `/models` directory, in reality, it tries to require `config.json` by default, just replace the `.json` by an `.js`